# android Dialogfragment onclicklistner separate class how to dismissed

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Android `Dialogfragment` `onclicklistner` separate class how to  dismissed 
i create the dialog view on the `onCreateView` method.

**My Code**

*Fragment Dialog*

```
public class ShareDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
String articleID;
MultiAutoCompleteTextView myMultiAutoCompleteTextView;
TextView Cancel;
Context context;
OnClickListenerCustom onClickListenerCustom;
String item[]={
        "January", "February", "March", "April",
        "May", "June", "July", "August",
        "September", "October", "November", "December"
};
public ShareDialogFragment() {

}
public static ShareDialogFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ShareDialogFragment fragment = new ShareDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    //ThemeOverlay_Material_Light
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.alert_dialog);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());


    Bundle arg = getArguments();
    if(arg!=null){
        articleID = getArguments().getString("ArticleId");
    }


}
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = activity;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share_dialog, container, false);
    Cancel = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Cancel);
    onClickListenerCustom = new OnClickListenerCustom(context);
    Cancel.setOnClickListener(onClickListenerCustom);

    myMultiAutoCompleteTextView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item));
    myMultiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());

    return view;
}
}
```

`OnClickListenerCustom` switch case hot dismiss `Dialog Fragment`

```
  public class OnClickListenerCustom implements OnClickListener {
    public Context context;
    String articleId, CompID;
    public int articlePost;
    public OnClickListenerCustom(Context context, String articleId, String CompID,int articlePost) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articleId = articleId;
        this.CompID = CompID;
        this.articlePost = articlePost;

    }
    public OnClickListenerCustom(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.starImage:
                v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                if (v.isActivated()) {
                    PatApi.isFavorites(articleId, "add", "article");
                } else if (!v.isActivated()) {
                    PatApi.isFavorites(articleId, "remove", "article");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.imagePat:
                v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                PatApi.isPat(CompID, articleId, "3");
                break;
            case R.id.share:
                FragmentManager manager = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();
                Bundle arg= new Bundle();
                arg.putString("ArticleId",String.valueOf(articlePost));
                ShareDialogFragment msgDialog = new ShareDialogFragment();
                msgDialog.show(manager,"Dialog");
                msgDialog.setArguments(arg);
                break;
            case R.id.RelativeWrapper:
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ArticleView.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.favoritesSwipe:
                v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                if (v.isActivated()) {
                    PatApi.isFavorites(articleId, "add", "article");
                } else if (!v.isActivated()) {
                    PatApi.isFavorites(articleId, "remove", "article");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.imageFavorites:
                //  v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
                M.t(context, "IMAGES");
                break;
            case R.id.Cancel:
                M.t(context, "Dismiss ");
                //how to Dismiss oc Click

        /*
                ShareDialogFragment superSimpleDlg = new ShareDialogFragment();
                superSimpleDlg.dismiss();*/

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try This        context.getDialog().dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

try with

popupWindow.dismiss();

Comment: Create one method inside your dialogclass and add .dismiss() and call that method from its object. (I am not sure but may be it will work)

Comment: my Dialog Fragment  onClick  ShareDialogFragment superSimpleDlg = new ShareDialogFragment();
superSimpleDlg.popupWindow.dismiss();   DialogFragment popupWindow = new Dialog(context); Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Dialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

Changes in ShareDialogFragment  class-------

Declare dialog globally...

```
 Dialog dialog;
```

In onCreate method initialize..

```
  dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
```

and in onCreateView

```
 onClickListenerCustom = new OnClickListenerCustom(context, dialog);
```

Changes in OnClickListenerCustom class----

Declare globally...

```
Dialog dialog;
```

Constructor

```
  public OnClickListenerCustom (Context context, Dialog dialog){
    this.context = context;
    this.dialog = dialog;
}
```

and

```
case R.id.Cancel:
            M.t(context, "Dismiss ");
            //how to Dismiss oc Click
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: ok..First tell me that when you click on Cancel then your program access goes in switch case(in Cancel case), I mean this line M.t(context, "Dismiss "); print something.

Comment: ShareDialogFragment.dismiss()' on a null object reference

Comment: print something in this method..public void dismissDialog(){
    fragment.dismiss();
} ....check that 
it call or not and also tell me proper error(Complete)

Comment: my  ShareDialogFragment newInstance not called(used)

Comment: then how does a dialog create..??

Comment: 1. onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    2.void onAttach(Activity activity) 3.View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)  i have these method